# Ordering by a custom date field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a date field in my model which allows me to enter a date in the format of DD/MM/YYYY for example 10/01/2015 - How would I go about ordering by this model entry? So I have the soonest dates displayed first?

Any help/hints would be great :)

Comment: use sql's `str_to_date`. `Model.scoped.select(*, str_to_date(field, format) as formatted_date").order("formatted_date desc")`

Comment: It is a date-field in the database or a string?